# How to delete all of a user's sessions except the current session he's logged in to in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

We have a certain issue where a user logs in with the same account in two different browsers (say chrome and firefox). If he changes his password in chrome, the firefox version just updates the session and does not expire the session.

I was looking for some code that will delete all of the user's sessions (in all other browsers, etc) except the current session through which he has changed his password.

```
other_session_ids = Session.where(:user_id => @current_user_instance.id).pluck(:session_id)
```

This is what I could come up with but I don't know how to do it for all EXCEPT the current user session.
How do I modify the above code so that the selected sessions are all but the current session?

The session table has the column user_id which I need to find based on the current user and then delete all but the current session if that makes sense.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user changes their password, you should also invalidate the current session and issue a new one. This is why many websites ask you to log in again after a password change.

That being said, if you *really* want to keep the current session that was started using the old password, it should be something like this:

```rb
Session.where(user_id: user).where.not(id: current_session.id).delete_all
```

Comment: I'll try the above-mentioned code and let you know. I'll also recommend the strategy of invalidating the current session and issuing a new one to the senior dev and ask if it's something we should do because, to be honest, it sounds like the proper way to implement password change.